# How to display an element in the middle of CSS3 animation

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, keyframe, css-animations

In this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jRQLV/), I want to display the element just in a step of the animation. However, it is not possible, because if I set `display:none` in the main `CSS` rule, the animation will not override it.

```
#test {
    -webkit-animation: test 2s;
    display:none; // here is the problem, as the animation does not override it.
}

@-webkit-keyframes test {
    0%{margin:5px}
    20%{display:block}
    70%{margin:40px}
}
```

Note that this is a simplified example, and in practice, I need to use `display:none` to hide the element before it becomes visible by the animation. Thus, other tricks like `opacity` does not satisfy my need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, if you want to hide the element and just show it when the animation starts, make use of visibility property like this:

```
#test {
  -webkit-animation: test 2s;
  visibility:hidden;
 }

@-webkit-keyframes test {
   0%{margin:5px}
  20%{visibility:visible}
  70%{margin:40px}
}
```

[**fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/e3BKg/)